# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher when running bash file to build the project

Tags: linux, maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have maven 2 installed. When I use mvn clean or mvn install in the app root it works fine.

But when I am trying to use maven install inside a bash script, I got the above exception:

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#dirname='/home/myuser/workspace/myapp'
DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)
cd  $DIRECTORY
mvn install -s resources/settings.xml $1
```

it was working fine with maven 3, but after I installed maven 2 and configured it, it stopped working and gave me above exception. I don't know what is the problem, since the regular build, mvn install works, but building from the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple of possibilities...

- One, as posted [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/sreekanth/entry/java_lang_noclassdeffounderror_org_codehaus), you have both M2_REPO and M3_REPO variables defined.
- Or you are facing [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4604) issue related to maven3 and M2_HOME
- The other is that somehow the JRE is getting used instead of JDK when run from the batch file!

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue when my M2_HOME environment variable points to an incorrect location.

Try to:

```
$ cd $M2_HOME
```