# Maven Installation - Environment Variables

Tags: java, windows, maven

I am using Maven for the first time on Windows 7 and getting this error:

`ERROR: JAVA_HOME` is set to an invalid directory.

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
```

Please set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation

> Java version "1.6.0_29" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_29-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)

I've read everywhere online about how to set up the variables properly in windows for a Maven installation, also on this site, but, I can't seem to get my installation working.

Here's my set-up:

System Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
```

Path

```
C:\apache-maven\src\bin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seemed it was a problem with the latest version of Maven.

I used Maven 2.2.1 with the same set-up and it run with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed it was a problem with the latest version of Maven. I used Maven 2.2.1 with the same set-up and it run with no problems.

Comment: but your JAVA_HOME seems to be bad anyway

Answer (score 4):

thats because your JAVA_HOME is incorrect

set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03`

also some systems , maven might still throw error because if the path to Java Directory has `space` i.e Space between `Program` and `Files` in the path

You might as well move the java to someother path without space

instead of

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
```

to

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
```

Edit

---

Double-quoting the value of JAVA_HOME can also cause this problem

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0"
```

doesn't work for me, but this does:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0
```

Comment: I have never had a problem on windows with `C:\Program Files\Java`. Have you? I would in fact consider `C:\Program Files\Java` better since windows JDK installers, as far as i have seen since 1.6, install here by default.

Answer (score 2):

set `JAVA_HOME` to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03 (without bin)

Comment: Thanks man, seems I have moved along a step, but still an error message: Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Comment: Is that an error when you execute maven, or is it an error when maven builds / compiles your project? Can you post the command you are executing and the complete error message.

Comment: mvn archetype:generate

the complete error message is:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launche
r.Launcher

Comment: have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198677/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-launcher-launche

Answer (score 0):

For environment variable of JAVA_HOME should be like this  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\" without bin. Please note that likely you have 2 version of Java installed. Make sure which one that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks man, seems I have moved along a step, but still an error message:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be like this C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

Hope this will work!